# Magento customer group - price increase

Tags: magento

This may sound bizarre - I need a customer group that when they login into magento they see a price increase.

The reason for it is the online price is going to be cheaper than the instore products. So I'm going to setup a user for the sales staff to login to so they can process the orders - but obviously we need to increase the prices.

Is there a way to do this, it basically just need to be something like 10% more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we decided to create a new store that had the 'instore prices'

Answer (score 1):

Quickest solution might be an extension. Google search found this: http://www.webtexsoftware.com/customer-group-prices-magento-extension

Comment: This extension is currently unavailable for purchase —
we are working hard on fixing some issues.
Sorry for the inconvenience, and please come back later. Thats the current message on that - also not sure if it does a price increase!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the default price the higher price.  Then setup tier pricing for the lower price. Associate all the groups except your sales reps to the tier price.